# Bridged interfaces and Tailscale "Raspberry"

Tags: interface, vpn, bridge, tailscale

Im trying to connect my apple tv to my home network and since the apple tv doesnt support vpn, ithought of getting a raspberry and setup tailscale on it and bridge eth0 and eth1 so that the apple tv gets vpn connection.

what i have done

```
    sudo brctl addbr br0
    
    sudo brctl addif br0 eth0 eth1
    
    
    nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf
        denyinterfaces eth0 eth1
    
    nano /etc/network/interfaces
        auto br0
        iface br0 inet dhcp
        bridge_ports eth0 eth1
    
    
    sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tailscale0 -j MASQUERADE
    sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -o tailscale0 -j ACCEPT
    sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tailscale0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
    
    sudo iptables -A INPUT -i tailscale0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    
    i add 1 for the table
    
    sudo ip route add default dev tailscale0 table vpnout
    sudo ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev br0 table vpnout
    
    sudo ip rule add from 192.168.0.0/24 table vpnout
    sudo ip rule add to 1192.168.0.0/24 table vpnout
    
    what happened is that i can get internet connection on eth1 but not routing tailscale traffic through eth1
    
    ifconfig
    
        br0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
            inet 192.168.0.107  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
            inet6 fe80::20e:c6ff:fe56:48a5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
            ether 00:0e:c6:56:48:a5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 6485  bytes 1781523 (1.6 MiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 1717  bytes 247950 (242.1 KiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    
    eth0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
            ether b8:27:eb:88:2b:90  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 8128  bytes 2260563 (2.1 MiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 3001  bytes 418999 (409.1 KiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    
    eth1: flags=4163  mtu 1500
            ether 00:0e:c6:56:48:a5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 1280  bytes 152865 (149.2 KiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 4534  bytes 1581066 (1.5 MiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    
    lo: flags=73  mtu 65536
            inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
            inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
            loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
            RX packets 2  bytes 78 (78.0 B)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 2  bytes 78 (78.0 B)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    
    tailscale0: flags=4305  mtu 1280
            inet 100.108.x.x  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 100.108.x.x
            inet6 fe80::7e1e:4058:6116:d2f5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
            unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)
            RX packets 16  bytes 1486 (1.4 KiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 24  bytes 1694 (1.6 KiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo

> sudo ip rule add to 1192.168.0.0/24 table vpnout